# Why my last named group catches everything else?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So, I have these data that come from SMSes exported to text that I want to be able to extract and create a better report than plain text, so I have a file full of these lines:

```
1.   01 mag 2015   10:55:08 AM   stringOne  PersonName                       +999999999999  MultilineText
```

Let me break it down:

1. "1." is like a line number
2. "01 mag 2015   10:55:08 AM" is the date
3. "stringOne" is a string that can be either "stringOne" or "stringTwo"
4. "PersonName" is a string that represents the name of the person
5. "+999999999999" is the phone number
6. "MultilineText" is a multiline string that can contain anything

I am using `Regex.Matches` to get the `MatchCollection` to iterate on.

I can get everything to work if I don't include the last group, and I really need to get these data, so here is the regular expression I am using that successfully retrieves the data without the last group:

```
@"(?<lineNumber>\d{1,3}\.   )(?<date>\d{2} \w{3} \d{4}   \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2} (AM|PM))\s*(stringOne|stringTwo)\s*(?<from>\w+)\s*(?<celnumber>\+?\d+)"
```

I tried to add the following part to that regular expression:

```
(?<text>.*)
```

However, I don't correctly get the multiline text, I do get some data but when it goes multiline it is cut out.

Then, I have tried to use this instead:

```
(?<text>(.|\n)*)
```

I only get one line as result.

So, how can I get that last "piece" of information as a multiline text?

Comment: On a sidenote, I see from your regex that spaces (`\s`) between the `<date>`, `stringOne|StringTwo`, `<from>` and `<celnumber>` are optional (`*` quantifier = 0 or more). Probably a good idea to make it required? (`+` quantifier = 1 or more)

Comment: @ohaal yes, lol, that is probably  a good idea, because they are indeed required =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<lineNumber>\d{1,3}\.   )(?<date>\d{2} \w{3} \d{4}   \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2} (AM|PM))\s*(stringOne|stringTwo)\s*(?<from>\w+)\s*(?<celnumber>\+?\d+)\s*(?<text>[\s\S]*?)(?=\n[ ]*\d+\.|$)
```

You can try this.

`(?<text>[\s\S]*?)(?=\n[ ]*\d+\.|$)` will catpure multiline text untill it finds a newline which has a number and `.`.The lookahead checks for it but doesnt consume it

Comment: thank you very much! it seems to work, can you explain the "(?<text>[\s\S]*?)(?=\n[ ]*\d+\.|$)" part? I'm worried that since I'm displaying the data using Match.Groups["text"].ToString() some text will be missing

Comment: the "text" part will contain only "[\s\S]*?" right?

Comment: "The lookahead checks for it but doesnt consume it" what is the command that specifies this?

Comment: @Robson `(?=something)`.anything after `(?= ` is lookahead and will not be consumed

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the singleline operator that will make `.` match newline symbols, and the multiline option `(?m)` that will enable us to control start of a *line*. I'd also recommend to replace literal spaces with `\s` since it will help with eventual future debugging:

Here is a regex with the inline `(?s)` and `(?m)` options:

```
(?sm)(?<lineNumber>\d{1,3}\.\s+)(?<date>\d{2}\s+\w{3}\s+\d{4}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s*(AM|PM))\s*(stringOne|stringTwo)\s*(?<from>\w+)\s*(?<celnumber>\+?\d+)(?<text>.*?)(?=\z|^\s*\d+\.)
```

Or inside a program (`RegexOptions.Singleline` and `RegexOptions.Multiline`):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<lineNumber>\d{1,3}\.\s+)(?<date>\d{2}\s+\w{3}\s+\d{4}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s*(AM|PM))\s*(stringOne|stringTwo)\s*(?<from>\w+)\s*(?<celnumber>\+?\d+)(?<text>.*?)(?=\z|^\s*\d+\.)", RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fsm)(%3f%3clineNumber%3e%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%5c.%5cs%2b)(%3f%3cdate%3e%5cd%7b2%7d%5cs%2b%5cw%7b3%7d%5cs%2b%5cd%7b4%7d%5cs%2b%5cd%7b2%7d%5c%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%5c%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%5cs*(AM%7cPM))%5cs*(stringOne%7cstringTwo)%5cs*(%3f%3cfrom%3e%5cw%2b)%5cs*(%3f%3ccelnumber%3e%5c%2b%3f%5cd%2b)(%3f%3ctext%3e.*%3f)(%3f%3d%5cz%7c%5e%5cs*%5cd%2b%5c.)&i=1.+++01+mag+2015+++10%3a55%3a08+AM+++stringOne++PersonName+++++++++++++++++++++++%2b999999999999++Multiline%0d%0aText%0d%0a%0d%0a++2.+++01+mag+2015+++10%3a55%3a08+AM+++stringOne++PersonName+++++++++++++++++++++++%2b999999999999++Multiline%0d%0aText%0d%0a)

You might wonder what `\z` does: it matches the end of the string irrespective of the multiline flag that modifies the meaning of `^` and `$` anchors.

Please check the C# code:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<lineNumber>\d{1,3}\.\s+)(?<date>\d{2}\s+\w{3}\s+\d{4}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s*(AM|PM))\s*(stringOne|stringTwo)\s*(?<from>\w+)\s*(?<celnumber>\+?\d+)(?<text>.*?)(?=\z|^\s*\d+\.)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var strr = "1.   01 mag 2015   10:55:08 AM   stringOne  PersonName                       +999999999999  Multiline\r\nText\r\n    2.   01 mag 2015   10:55:08 AM   stringOne  PersonName                       +222229999  Multiline\r\nText";
var mth = rx.Matches(strr).Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. I only get one Match out of the MatchCollection with this regex. I need that the regex analyzes the whole file and not only one line

Comment: @Robson: Why not iterate over each line and apply the regex? I would imagine that is cheaper than using regex on the entirety of the file?

Comment: @ohaal that is a good idea, even thought i don't care about performance in this case, i am indeeed analyzing the whole file at once using StringReader.ReadToEnd()

Comment: If you have text with bullet points (each entry starts with a digit(s) + `.` + `space`, my regex should deal with them correctly.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. still it is returning only one line. @vks solution seems to work, I'm testing it

Comment: got it! the problem was that i wasn't clear enough aobut how the data was. so your solution worked only if the lines started with the degits, and if there was any white space the regex would fail. @vks got it right before you with the "(?=\n[ ]*\d+\.|$)". but really thanks you helped me a lot!

Comment: I have added the `\s*` after `^`. I still vote against using literal spaces in the regex pattern. vks did not even test his regex in real C# code.

Comment: i just copied his regex and putted it inside my code and it worked flawlessly. i really wanted to mark both of you as answers but stackoverflow doesn't allow it